# React Native [error Failed to run jetifier.]

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, apk

When I try to run the release APK in the emulator with this cmd :

`npx react-native run-android --variant=release`

It gives me error like this :

```
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
node:internal/fs/utils:348
    throw err;
    ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'node_modules'
    at readdirSync (node:fs:1451:3)
    at readDir (C:\Users\sapar\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\ReactNative\TextUtils\node_modules\jetifier\src\utils.js:14:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sapar\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\ReactNative\TextUtils\node_modules\jetifier\index.js:12:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sapar\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\ReactNative\TextUtils\node_modules\jetifier\bin\jetify:3:1) {
  errno: -4058,
  syscall: 'scandir',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'node_modules'
}

Node.js v18.13.0
error Failed to run jetifier.
Error: Command failed: C:\Users\sapar\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\ReactNative\TextUtils\node_modules\jetifier\bin\jetify
    at makeError (C:\Users\sapar\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\ReactNative\TextUtils\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at C:\Users\sapar\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\ReactNative\TextUtils\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Object.runAndroid [as func] (C:\Users\sapar\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\ReactNative\TextUtils\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:104:7)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\sapar\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\ReactNative\TextUtils\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:192:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

Android -> gradle.properties

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

I will try this to add to the line in  gradle.properties then remove the old node module folder and run `npm i`  and also run this cmd  `npx jetify` but still, the error is coming,

I don't know how to solve it, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

In Root Directory run this cmd,

```
npm install --save-dev jetifier --force
```

then,

```
npx jetify
```

then,

```
npm start --reset-cache
```

Finally run this cmd,

```
npx react-native run-android --variant=release
```

It work's for ME!